# Не могу понять запись создания взаимных ссылок между классами

Tags: java, классы, ссылки

У меня есть два класса: `Controller` и `Viewer`. Они вроде как связаны между собой. Можете подробнее объяснить эту запись? Не очень понятно что это и с чем едят, теорию про классы и про `this` прочитал.

```
class Controller {
    Controller(Viewer viewer) {
        this.viewer = viewer;
    }
}
class Viewer {
    Controller controller = new Controller(this);
}
```

Comment: что вам не ясно? из одно объект можно получить доступ к другому объекту и наоборот. Получить доступ значит вызвать публичные методы, обратиться к публичным полям.

Comment: Я тоже запись не понял. Код неправильный. Это не иннер класс, это 2 разных класса.

Answer (score 0):

всё я разобрался. таким образом мы в классе Controller имеем доступ к классу Viewer!

Comment: Старайтесь писать более детальные ответы.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/161332)

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy, он сам автор.